# How to access prediction from another python module?

Tags: python, python-module, self

I have a file *file_calling_class.py* that needs to access the prediction value from another python module in *file_with_class.py*. However, I do not know how to access the prediction. The function alone works fine if it is the only script but if I want to pass the *budget* value from *file_calling_class.py* to *file_with_class.py* by using self I do not know how to access the prediction result of *calculate_sales(self)*.

This is my *file_calling_class.py*

```
 import file_with_class

 budget = 100

 sales = file_with_class.CalcSales(budget=budget).__str__()
 print('Your sales are: ' +sales)
```

This is my *file_with_class.py*

```
 import pickle
 import pandas as pd




class CalcSales():

def __init__(self, budget: int):
    self.budget = budget
    self.sales = 0
    self.prediction = 0


def calculate_sales(self): 
    #budget = request.args.get('budget')
    print(self.budget) 
    budget = [int(self.budget)] 

    df = pd.DataFrame(budget, columns=['Marketing Budget']) 

    model = pickle.load(open('simple_linear_regression.pkl', 'rb'))

    prediction = model.predict(df) 

    self.prediction = int(prediction[0]) 

    # return(self.prediction)


def __str__ (self):
    return (str(self.prediction))
```

Output

```
  Your sales are: 0
```

which is just the value with which I initialized *self.prediction*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not invoking the `.calculate_sales()` method in your call. Try changing `sales = file_with_class.CalcSales(budget=budget).__str__()` in `file_calling_class.py` to:

```py
sales = file_with_class.CalcSales(budget=budget).calculate_sales().__str__()
```